# Main nav text showing in front of the header text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

so I made my website navigation responsive with the hamburger , and when I click it my text shows in front of the header text and I can't click them. I don't know why it is like that.
I added the position absolute to my banner so I can push it down and put it on the left side.

```css
header {
  background: url('../img/2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  z-index: 999;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
  <div class="sticky">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
      <!-- <h2>20.08 - 9 ЧАСА РАБОТА</h2> -->
    </div>

    <div class="expand">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="hamburger"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">PROCESS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>We Design and Develop</h2>
        <p>We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float: right` is a nightmare.  Consider using flex, or grid layouts to get what you want.

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: Yes this is using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The layout is weird, don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve... but having said that, the core issue that you asked in the question is that `banner` is overlapping your `main-nav`... to resolve, we just assign a lower `z-index` number to the `banner` div.

working **snippet below**:

```css
header {
  background: url('../img/2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  z-index: 999;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1 !important;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="sticky">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
      <!-- <h2>20.08 - 9 ЧАСА РАБОТА</h2> -->
    </div>

    <div class="expand">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="hamburger"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">PROCESS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>We Design and Develop</h2>
        <p>We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```